# base64 encoder returns undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, base64, encode

I'm trying to make an api request, to my server where i have some files, that I'm sending along.

I have made an array of custom objects, where i have two parameters, the file extension and the raw data base654 encoded

```
  onSubmitHandler = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const contactRequest = {
        email: this.state.email,
        name: this.state.name,
        message: this.state.message,
        files: this.state.files,
        result: this.state.files.map(file => ({
            "file": this.findFileTypeHandler(file.name), 
            "data": this.getBase64(file)
        }))
    }
    console.log(this.getBase64(this.state.files[0]))
    console.log(contactRequest)
}
```

the issue is in my getBase64 function

i havde tried several approaches.

```
    getBase64 = file => {
     let ans  = ''
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
    console.log(reader.result) //logged correctly here, but after undefined is returned
    ans = reader.result
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('error is ', error)
      return error;
    };
    return ans;
 }
```

the correct answer is logged correctly, but it returns undefined first. This is due to It's asynchronous behavior.

Is there a way, so i can make it wait till the function is loaded correctly.

I initially though about making a async await approach, but i think this would get messy, since I'm already planing, to use promises, when i make a post request to my server.

Comment: i will edit that

Comment: this: _I initially though about making a async await approach_ - just be careful when mixing 'callback' and 'Promise' logic as they don't mix well.

Comment: You are using React - a state managed environment. Is there a reason you don't set a state prop and then use that?

Comment: yeah i figured, this would be better, the reason, is that, the logic, only happens right before the request is sent, so i figured, i could make it work, without state.. but i would probably be cleaner?

Comment: You could set a `prop` so as not to affect your state data. That might be a wiser choice.

Comment: yeah, and then just overwrite the prop for each new file, added to the array?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: but how do i call the function, then and use the state, as the prop?

Comment: Listen for changes to the state property and fire on change.

Comment: yes but i have to execute the getbase64, function each time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187343/discussion-between-randy-casburn-and-baileyhaldwin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a simple one. Pass a callback function to the getBase64, and then the callback function will receive the result. Doesn't require that much of a modification:

```
getBase64 = (file, callBack) => {
    let ans = '';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        callBack(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = error => {
        console.log('error is ', error);
        return error;
    };
};
```

Which you can then use later on as:

`getBase64(target, res => console.log(res));`

Or if you want the result in a variable, you could do:

```
let b64;
getBase64(target, res => { b64 = res; });
```

Comment: yes i tried this initially, and decided to store the answer in a variable, to easier, see where the problem occurs

Comment: of course it does, the added `return` returns from the `onload` hander callback function, not the `getBase64()` function.

Comment: Yeah Randy is right, I'm going to run this somewhere real quick and figure out the probable scope issue then, update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's not a scope issue, it's an async issue.  The return statement in the `onload` is meaningless.   Have a look here to understand the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

check that

`FileBase type="file" multiple={false}`

My code looks like the below for reference.

```html
<FileBase 
    type="file"
    multiple={false}
    onDone={({base64}) => setListingData({ ...listingData, selectedFile: base64})}
/>
```